# IIS: 404 when visting PHP pages?

Tags: php, iis

I have tried reinstalling my whole web server, installing PHP, reinstalling PHP, everything.. I have tried every solution said by others on google but nothing works.

I have setup a subdomain to my default site and its throwing the IIS 404 error page when visting index.php, but not when visting index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried localhost? Are you redirecting to the right file at the correct folder? Another possiblity are the rights which can be edites in filezila for example. (777).

Another possibilty is you are using a controller which redirects to an invalid function. (Put exit('test'); at the top of your page to see if you can access the file to start with. From there on you can place exits piece by piece to see where your code fails.

Hopefully this helped.

Comment: Hi, just a question if this has been solved already. @josh hallow